# R regex: issues with character vectors containing NAs

Tags: regex, r

I was trying to collapse all multiple (2 or more) whitespace characters within elements of a vector into a single one, using `gsub()`, e.g.:

```
x1 <- c("  abc", "a b c    ", "a  b c")
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", x1)
[1] " abc"   "a b c " "a b c"
```

But as soon as the vector contains `NA` the substitution fails:

```
x2 <- c(NA, "  abc", "a b c    ", "a  b c")
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", x2)
[1] NA  " " " " " "
```

However, it works fine if one uses Perl-like regular expressions:

```
gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", x2, perl = TRUE)
[1] NA       " abc"   "a b c " "a b c"
```

Does anyone have suggestions as to why R's own regular expressions behave in that way? I'm using R 3.1.1 on Linux x86-64 if that helps.

Comment: Did you check adding more back slashes?  In R it is quite tricky. You usually need three to recognize these kind of expressions

Comment: @Llopis That's incorrect. The regex is actually `\s`, to which we prepend a single backslash to arrive at `\\s`.

Comment: Confirmed on OS X as well.  Both `\s` and `[[:space:]]` exhibit the behavior, while a literal space character (or space/tab character class) works fine.  I'm thinking bug in R.

Comment: @MarkReed Another user earlier pointed out that the problem does not occur under Windows. Such inconsistent behaviour might indeed be a bug.

Comment: under windows it works fine, so if is is a bug( i don't think so )  good luck to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't poked at the source code but it also works if you use the `useBytes=TRUE` parameter (without the `perl=TRUE` parameter). From the help: "*if `useBytes` is `TRUE` the matching is done byte-by-byte rather than character-by-character.*" That may be part of why it's failing in `gsub`.

However, `regexpr`, `regexec` and `gregexpr` each find all the correct positions (I have substituted `\\s` with `[[:space:]]:` for readability and only used output from `regexpr`:

```
regexpr("[[:space:]]{2,}", x2)

## [1] NA  1  1  1
## attr(,"match.length")
## [1] NA  5  9  6
```

So, the regex itself is fine.

Update: a quick glance at `do_gsub` in R 3.1.1's `grep.c` didn't yield much insight (it's a twisted maze of `if/else` statements :-), but I'd almost want to call this a bug.

Comment: What? a bug in Regex?  How could anyone tell?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to wrap this question up: as several others suggested, the behaviour is in fact a bug. Reported and confirmed here:

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16009